# What may help stop a For Loop from defaulting onto one object in Maya python?

Tags: python, maya

What I am trying to figure out is how to get the legs positioned in their designated spots that are in def position_legs. I realized that in def build, the for loop is making it difficult because it causes to set to a defaulted geometry such as cmds.xform(object_legs, translation=[2.0,2.5,-4.0]) to ALL the other three legs which is not what I want. I am basically trying to figure out how I can set each leg in each corner of the table. Note that I am trying to build a procedural geometry table in python but I am sending the python code from Visual Studio Code to Maya. Let me know if I need to explain more. I appreciate the help :)

```py
class Table(object):

    def __init__(self):
         
         self.height = 0.5
         self.width = 5.0
         self.depth = 9.0

         self.legs = 4
         self.leg_height = 5.0
         self.leg_width = 0.5
         self.leg_depth = 0.5


    def make_top(self):
        xform, shape = cmds.polyCube(height=self.height, width=self.width, depth=self.depth) # table-top
        return xform
    
    def make_legs(self):
        xform, shape = cmds.polyCube(height=self.leg_height, width=self.leg_width, depth=self.leg_depth)
        return xform
    
    def position_top(self, obj_top):
        cmds.xform(obj_top, translation=[0,5.0,0])

    def position_legs(self, object_legs):
        cmds.xform(object_legs, translation=[-2.0,2.5,-4.0])
        cmds.xform(object_legs, translation=[2.0,2.5,4.0])
        cmds.xform(object_legs, translation=[-2.0,2.5,4.0])
        cmds.xform(object_legs, translation=[2.0,2.5,-4.0]) # -------For loop defaults to this leg

    def build(self):
        # Table Top
        xform_obj = self.make_top() # make the top
        self.position_top(xform_obj) # position the top
        # Table legs
        list_legs = []
        for leg_num in range(self.legs):
            xform_obj_legs = self.make_legs()
            self.position_legs(xform_obj_legs)

        cmds.group(name='table_top', empty=True)
        cmds.group(name='legs_grp', empty=True)
        cmds.parent([xform_obj], 'table_top')
        cmds.parent([list_legs[0], list_legs[1], list_legs[2], list_legs[3]], 'legs_grp')
        cmds.group(name='Table', empty=True)
        cmds.parent(['legs_grp', 'table_top'], 'Table')
```

Comment: you do nothing to fill `list_legs`, `make_legs` only makes 1 leg, `position_legs` transforms the leg 4 times

Answer (score 0):

What the code is doing, is that it is running all the transformations for each and every legs, thus all the legs defaults to the last line of code.

What you need to do is find a way where each leg gets each individual positions.

What I attempted is a solution, but there may be many other ways to tackle this particular situation, what I recommend is to find other ways to tackle this issue.

Solution:

```py
def make_legs(self, pos): # this will now get the position as argument and transform the leg
        xform, shape = cmds.polyCube(height=self.leg_height, width=self.leg_width, depth=self.leg_depth)
        cmds.xform(xform, translation=pos)
        return xform

def get_legs_positions(self):
        positions = (
            [-2.0,2.5,-4.0],
            [2.0,2.5,4.0],
            [-2.0,2.5,4.0],
            [2.0,2.5,-4.0]
        )
        return positions

for leg_pos in self.get_legs_positions(): 
            xform_obj_legs = self.make_legs(leg_pos)
```